# Google sites not passing parameters to embedded widgets - only on some pages

Tags: web, parameters, google-apps-script, google-sites

Here's the very basic widget code:

```
function doGet(e) {
    Logger.log(e.parameter.foo)
    //... return html stuff
}
```

Pretty basic. I have this widget embedded on a test page. The url of which is:

```
https://sites.google.com/a/<domain>/<site>/test
```

If I navigate to that page using this url:

```
https://sites.google.com/a/<domain>/<site>/test/?foo=bar
```

Logger prints

```
bar
```

Great.

On a separate page, I have the *exact same* widget embedded. If I call

```
https://sites.google.com/a/<domain>/<site>/another/page/?foo=bar
```

Logger prints

```
undefined
```

????

The *only* difference between that page and the others is that it has been created *from a template* by a Google Apps Script.

Should this affect parameter behavior???

Any help would be greatly appreciated - I'm at a complete loss over this.

Thanks.